# How can I create a fixed length array of strings(chat messages) paired with keys (userID) in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, associative-array

I've got a chat bot setup to receive chat messages using a standard instant messaging protocal. As it is now, the chat bot responds to a client each time a message is sent. This means that it responds to each line sent. Instead of doing this, I'd like to store 5 messages at a time from a client and respond on a time based interval instead of on a per message based interval. Here's an example of per message based interval:

```
Human: Hey there!
Bot: Hello!
Human: What is your favorite color?
Bot: Green
Human: Do you like animals?
Bot: I like your mother.
Human: HEY! >:(
```

What I'd like to do is store 5 lines at a time for each user talking to the bot. Since each user has a unique userID, I can store the messages in a one-to-many relationship. It would look something like this:

```
UserID:(Message1, Message2, Message3, Message4, Message5)
```

So the above example would be stored as:

```
Human: ("Hey there!", "What is your favorite color?","Do you like animals?","HEY! >:(", Message5)
```

I'd like the list to be limited, though, and replace the first entry when a new entry appears and the list is full. Basically, it is always keeping the most recent 5 chat messages in this list.

I'm not sure what type of object or function I should use to create this type of associative array. I need to be able to check to see if a user is already added, and expand or collapse the list if a user stops talking to the bot (we don't want an infinite list / we should garbage collect lists which haven't been used in a while)

How can I efficiently set this up so that I don't run into resource problems, memory leaks, etc?

Comment: Why not use a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx)?  Something like this:  `Dictionary<string, int> chatMessages = new Dictionary<string, int>();`.

Comment: Because as I understand it "The order of elements in a dictionary is non-deterministic. The notion of order simply is not defined for hashtables. So don't rely on enumerating in the same order as elements were added to the dictionary. That's not guaranteed." Which creates problems if I want to store only the newest 5 chat messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need a `Dictionary<string, Queue<string>>`. Methods like this will work. (I'm freehanding this. Pardon any compilation errors.)

```
Dictionary<string, Queue<string>> messageQueue = new Dictionary<string, Queue<string>>();

void AddMessage(string userName, string message)
{
    Queue<string> queue;
    if (!messageQueue.TryGetValue(userName, out queue))
    {
        queue = new Queue<string>();
        messageQueue.Add(userName, queue);
    }
    queue.Enqueue(message);
    while (queue.Count > 5)
        queue.Dequeue();
}

void RemoveUser(string userName)
{
    messageQueue.Remove(userName);
}
```

Comment: This seems like a possible solution. Is this going to create problems with regards to continuously adding new users? What I mean is will old userID keys be deleted if they are not access after a certain time, or will searching the dictionary keep old keys within the dictionary?

Comment: You'd have to manually clean up when appropriate. Hence the `RemoveUser` method shown above. There's nothing in the the bare .NET framework that implements the sort of cleanup you want. You'll have to determine when to clean up according to the rules of whatever you're implementing. Just call `RemoveUser` once you've determined that a user is gone.

Comment: Or, in the form of a question: What are your rules for determining when a user's messages should be discarded? Is it based on something outside the scope of this question? (For example, is it based on a timeout period?) If so, post another question. If it's based solely on the state of the message queue (maybe the rule is to only store up to *n* messages total across all users, or maybe it's to only store *n* users), that is within the scope of this question.